# Can't upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 now support has expired, how do I get upgraded?

Tags: xubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a 21.10 xubuntu system to 22.04.  When I try 'do-release-upgrade' I see the following:-

root@t470# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
root@t470#

There is one 'held back' package which I think my be causing my problem, I can't 'unhold' it now though as the repositories are not available.

Help!

Comment: You may have to install clean instead of upgrading.  Hopefully someone will come along and contradict me...  And Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: there may be "old" repositories you can add to your apt list instead of the usual ones, otherwise you might have to clean install (and next time upgrade before EOL)

Comment: Yes, thanks all, the 'old repositories' worked well, all updated now! :-)